# Converting line items in a row in to columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

[Input output image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLcAf.jpg)I am new to python coding and stuck in data cleansing steps. I want to convert line items in row in to column and summarize the results

My dataframe is as below:

```
ITEM    CATEGORY    LOCATION    DATE    QTY
21221   SHOES              HYD       1/1/2019   23
21222   TSHIRT             HYD       1/2/2019   54
21223   CAPS               HYD       1/3/2019   2
21221   SHOES              HYD       1/1/2019   23
21222   TSHIRT             HYD       1/1/2019   28
21223   CAPS               HYD       1/2/2019   36
21223   CAPS               HYD       1/1/2019   5
```

And I want it to be like this:

```
ITEM  CATEGORY  LOCATION  1/1/2019  1/2/2019  1/3/2019
21221 SHOES     HYD             46         0         0
21222 TSHIRT    HYD             28        54         0
21223 CAPS      HYD              5         2        36
```

I am using the following code but of no help...

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
mydata = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/data.csv", delimiter=',' , header='infer',
                    names=None, index_col=None, usecols=None, squeeze=False,
                    engine='python')
mydata.head()
pivot1 = pd.pivot_table(mydata, index=["ITEM NO", "CATEGORY", "LOCATION"])
mydata.groupby(['pivot1','DATE'], as_index = False).sum().pivot('pivot1','DATE').fillna(0)
```

Please help

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide us with your code so that we have context to help you. Note also that this forum is not meant to be a code-writing service.

Comment: I am new to this community. Edited and added my working code. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

you may try this:

```
import pandas as pd 
mydata = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/data.csv", parse_dates=[3])
df =mydata.groupby(['ITEM', 'CATEGORY', 'LOCATION', 'DATE'])['QTY'].sum().unstack().fillna(0)
print(df)
```

Here is the result I got:

```
DATE                     1/1/2019  1/2/2019  1/3/2019
ITEM  CATEGORY LOCATION                              
21221 SHOES    HYD           46.0       0.0       0.0
21222 TSHIRT   HYD           28.0      54.0       0.0
21223 CAPS     HYD            5.0      36.0       2.0
```

Comment: Thanks. But when I am trying it, I am getting below error.  "C:Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 6665, in groupby   observed=observed, **kwargs)

  File "C:anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 2152, in groupby
    return klass(obj, by, **kwds)

  File "C:\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 599, in __init__
    mutated=self.mutated)

  File "C:\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 3291, in _get_grouper
    raise KeyError(gpr)

KeyError: 'DATE'

Comment: you can add a parameter in read_csv method, see the updated code.

Comment: I tried above steps. But still getting keyerror(gpr). Any suggestions